# Visual Studio code extension to tidy code in php

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I need an extension in Visual Studio Code, to make my PHP code clean. I am a total beginner. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Extension [php cs fixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=junstyle.php-cs-fixer) by User "junstyle".

It will turn this:

```
   <?php 

$a = array("a" => 
"#test",

"b"           =>  "foo")
```

into this (on save, if you so wish):

```
$a = ['a'         => '#test',
    'b'           => 'foo']
```

*How* php-cs-fixer transforms things can be a bit tricky to configure. I have created a config file `.vscode/php-cs-fixer.config.php` in my VSCode workspace. But I don't remember many details.